# Of what significance is the solution to the game of checkers in AI research?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I have been doing some research into artificial intelligence and I came across [a 2007 paper titled "Checkers is Solved"](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/317/5844/1518.abstract) on the game of checkers being solved by AI techniques after more than 16 years of trial. A solution to the game is defined by the team as  "determining the final result in a game with no mistakes made by either player". The search for a solution started back in 1989 and it was finally found in 2007. Of what importance is this to the field of AI?

Comment: Could you try to be a bit more specific? In its current state your question is a good conversation starter, but not a good fit for programmers.

Comment: It might be useful if you cite the paper that contains this information. If possible, provide a link to the paper or someplace where the paper can be obtained.

Comment: Did the solution use something other than min-max?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you explore AI, you do so first with a problem space that is relatively small and bounded by specific rules, so that you can prove your techniques.

Checkers is such a space.  It therefore makes an ideal playground for AI explorations.  This is also true of chess, although checkers is a smaller problem space, and therefore is more suitable to simpler explorations of AI. Board games like chess and checkers are easily modelled in a computer using a two-dimensional array.

As your knowledge improves, you can begin to alter your techniques and apply AI to more complex and non-deterministic domains, like human interactions.

Comment: Or the game go, which was once thought to be immune compared to relatively simple games such as chess. Go is now also being (somewhat) successfully attacked by AI techniques.

Comment: @DavidHammen, if humans can play it, AI can compete.

Comment: @DavidHammen I think Go is still lands in the "can't be solved" zone for the normal 19x19 boards - there's simply too many possible board positions.  But I'm not completely certain.

Comment: Current Go engines are using a Monte Carlo randomization which produces good enough moves to compete with accomplished amateurs.